# find a letters in a string from table is only working with the first item

Tags: string, lua, find, lua-table

hi i cannot explain it without the lua code
the problem is that its just catch the first item of the table
if i wrote te = "f... you" it will return true , but if i've wrote , te = "a.." it'll return false -_-

i'm just trying to catch up the bad words from strings , here is the code
* sorry for the bad words i just didn't wrote them fully

```lua
local te = "f... you"
badwords = {
"f...",
"a..",
"s...",
"b....",
"g..",
"w....",
}
```

And the function:

```
function isTextContainsBadwords(str)
  for i,v in ipairs(badwords) do
    if str:find(v) then
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
print(tostring(isTextContainsBadwords(te)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you iterate the table `badwords`, the first string in it `"f..."` doesn't match `a..` and else block has a `return false` in it; which terminates the execution of code.

You don't need an `else` block there. Just take the `return false` outside of the `for` loop.

```
function isTextContainsBadwords(str)
    for i,v in ipairs(badwords) do
        if str:find(v) then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

Comment: ah , i didn't notice this , thanks very much ^^ Dream Eater ^^